# Como trabalhar com o I18N em PHP e Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony-2, twig, i18n

Existe algum complemento para o Symfony que permita trabalhar com i18n e arquivos .po e .mo ou semelhante ou é necessário realmente implementar uma solução para isso? O ideal seria que eu pudesse chamar a tradução tanto no twig, como no Controller. Se existe qual ou quais seriam as opções?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O próprio Symfony tem um componente para internacionalização, e são utilizados arquivos XML ou YAML para isso. Você ainda pode ler a tradução de um banco de dados. Dê uma olhada na documentação deles a respeito:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

É possível utilizar a internacionalização tanto no PHP quanto em arquivos de template (usando Twig). No primeiro caso, após chamar o serviço de internacionalização do container de serviços, é só traduzir assim:

```
$translator->trans('Hi!');
```

Já no Twig, é só usar o filtro `trans`:

```
{{ "Hi!"|trans }}
```